# using tfs build pull a prebuilt common components into another build

Tags: tfs, msbuild, build-process, tfsbuild

I'm looking for advice on how to have team build 2013 use a pre-compiled common that is not checked in or part of the workspace. 
Everything we build is QNX based and we are refactoring out a common set of components to be shared across all projects.  I've looked at Go and NuGet but that seems like a lot effort for something like this.
What is the best way to pull a prebuilt common into a TFS Team Build?

Comment: Nuget Publish.  Nuget Install.  That's the most common binary-repository method that I know of.

Comment: Thanks.  We have looked at NuGet a little and nothing we build uses solution files so it didn't stand out as a possible solution.  May be worth a second look.

Comment: Nuget is about creating binary packages....so having a .sln file isn't a pre-req.  You just need output files...to package them up.  Another option is "apache ivy command line"....which was the only alternative before nuget.    http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/standalone.html  but that would be a higher start up cost than nuget if you're not java familiar.

Answer (score 0):

So you would nuget "publish" a package.

https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package

then your build would nuget restore using a packages.config file (aka, NOT a .sln file)

```
nuget restore [<solution>|<packages.config file>]
```

https://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference

What VS (in a .sln file) is auto-voodooing some of this for you.

But using command line nuget (especially for the restore)....is a way to get a package out of nuget if you're build isn't based on .sln file.

Another way to think about it is...when you run "nuget install" or "nuget update", VS is auto-voodooing you a packages.config file.  While you might look at the file and find it interesting, you're not consumed on how it works in the background of VS.  But if you want to manually pull nuget packages....you will be very interested in how it is created.

What I would do as a test would be:

1. Create a dummy .sln,csproj file.
2. Nuget add a few random packages (using "Manage Nuget Packages for this solution).
3. Take that packages.config that was auto-voodoo created for you.... and move it to a clean directory.
4. See if you can run **nuget.exe restore** on it, and get/pull the packages (aka, you're testing that you can do a pull... without a .sln file being involved).

If that works...than it becomes of matter of creating your own nuget repository..creating your own published-package...and repeating #4 above to get that package out.

Make sense?

So I have these files in a clean directory:

```
.\packages.config
.\.nuget\NuGet.Config
.\.nuget\NuGet.exe
.\.nuget\NuGet.targets
```

Then I run in the comamand-window:

```
.\.nuget\nuget.exe restore  .\packages.config -PackagesDirectory .\MyPackages
```

And all the packages listed in "packages.config" will download to : .\MyPackages

Note, if you have a custom nuget repository, that will need to be configured...but cross that bridge when you get there.